# Morris charts dynamic response Values not showing

Tags: javascript, charts, morris.js

The Data structure is the same as my response, but labels are showing correctly and the values are not showing please some one help me

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",url: url1, dataType: "json",
            success: function(response)
            {   


               var areaBar = Morris.Bar({
                element: 'ct_chart_2',
                data: response,
                xkey: 'year',
                ykeys: ['BKG', 'BKM','CSD','others'],
                labels: ['BKG', 'BKM', 'CSD','Others'],
                gridLineColor: 'rgba(33,33,33,0.1)',
                stacked: true,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                barColors: ['#00acf0','#d0d962','#d4d4d4','#E45TFS'],
                resize: true,
                gridTextColor:'#878787',
                gridTextFamily:"Roboto",
                parseTime: false,
                fillOpacity:0.2
            }); 
            }

        });
```

this is my ajax response result

```
[
    {"year":"2004","BKG":"1211","BKM":"119","CSD":"334","others":"3"},
    {"year":"2005","BKG":"1599","BKM":"168","CSD":"1586","others":"6"},
    {"year":"2006","BKG":"1088","BKM":"161","CSD":"1213","others":"3"},
    {"year":"2007","BKG":"1018","BKM":"118","CSD":"1552","others":"5"},
    {"year":"2008","BKG":"1011","BKM":"335","CSD":"1406","others":"8"},
    {"year":"2009","BKG":"912","BKM":"153","CSD":"1935","others":"3"},
    {"year":"2010","BKG":"825","BKM":"214","CSD":"2012","others":"1"},
    {"year":"2011","BKG":"727","BKM":"208","CSD":"2821","others":"12"},
    {"year":"2012","BKG":"905","BKM":"301","CSD":"4336","others":"4"},
    {"year":"2013","BKG":"731","BKM":"371","CSD":"3034","others":"6"},
    {"year":"2014","BKG":"719","BKM":"506","CSD":"2354","others":"6"},
    {"year":"2015","BKG":"571","BKM":"630","CSD":"2055","others":"6"},
    {"year":"2016","BKG":"488","BKM":"641","CSD":"1650","others":"7"},
    {"year":"2017","BKG":"5","BKM":"0","CSD":"0","others":"0"},
    {"year":"2019","BKG":"1","BKM":"0","CSD":"0","others":"0"}
]
```

Please Help me ...

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you specify the `ykeys` correctly like:

```
ykeys: ['BKG', 'BKM', 'CSD', 'others']
```

Note, you are using **lowercase** `ykeys` like `bkg`, `bkm` and `csd` on your code:

## Example:

```js
const data = [{"year":"2004","BKG":"1211","BKM":"119","CSD":"334","others":"3"},{"year":"2005","BKG":"1599","BKM":"168","CSD":"1586","others":"6"},{"year":"2006","BKG":"1088","BKM":"161","CSD":"1213","others":"3"},{"year":"2007","BKG":"1018","BKM":"118","CSD":"1552","others":"5"},{"year":"2008","BKG":"1011","BKM":"335","CSD":"1406","others":"8"},{"year":"2009","BKG":"912","BKM":"153","CSD":"1935","others":"3"},{"year":"2010","BKG":"825","BKM":"214","CSD":"2012","others":"1"},{"year":"2011","BKG":"727","BKM":"208","CSD":"2821","others":"12"},{"year":"2012","BKG":"905","BKM":"301","CSD":"4336","others":"4"},{"year":"2013","BKG":"731","BKM":"371","CSD":"3034","others":"6"},{"year":"2014","BKG":"719","BKM":"506","CSD":"2354","others":"6"},{"year":"2015","BKG":"571","BKM":"630","CSD":"2055","others":"6"},{"year":"2016","BKG":"488","BKM":"641","CSD":"1650","others":"7"},{"year":"2017","BKG":"5","BKM":"0","CSD":"0","others":"0"},{"year":"2019","BKG":"1","BKM":"0","CSD":"0","others":"0"}]

var areaBar = Morris.Bar({
  element: 'ct_chart_2',
  data: data,
  xkey: 'year',
  ykeys: ['BKG', 'BKM','CSD','others'],
  labels: ['BKG', 'BKM', 'CSD','Others'],
  gridLineColor: 'rgba(33,33,33,0.1)',
  stacked: true,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  barColors: ['#00acf0','#d0d962','#d4d4d4','#fsddfs'],
  resize: true,
  gridTextColor:'#878787',
  gridTextFamily:"Roboto",
  parseTime: false,
  fillOpacity:0.2
});
```

```css
#ct_chart_2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="ct_chart_2"></div>
```

Comment: const data = [{"year":"2004","BKG":"1211","BKM":"119","CSD":"334","others":"3"},{"year":"2005","BKG":"1599","BKM":"168","CSD":"1586","others":"6"},{"year":"2006","BKG":"1088","BKM":"161","CSD":"1213","others":"3"},{"year":"2007","BKG":"1018","BKM":"118","CSD":"1552","others":"5"},{"year":"2008","BKG":"1011","BKM":"335","CSD":"1406","others":"8"},]
like this its working  but ajax response not working labels are working not values

Comment: @RafiP and what is your response, if it is the one you have included on your question, my code is working with that `dataset`. Otherwise, please include it, or add the `ajax` call code.

Comment: var url1='regiondata.php';
$.ajax(
{
type: "POST",url: url1, dataType: "json",
success: function(response)
{ 
 const data1 = JSON.stringify(response);
 var areaBar = Morris.Bar({
 element: 'ct_chart_2',
 data: data1,
 xkey: 'year',
 ykeys: ['BKG', 'BKM','CSD','others'],
   labels: ['BKG', 'BKM', 'CSD','Others'],
 gridLineColor: 'rgba(33,33,33,0.1)',
 stacked: true,
 hideHover: 'auto',
 barColors: ['#00acf0','#d0d962','#d4d4d4','#E45TFS'],
 resize: true,
 gridTextColor:'#878787',
 gridTextFamily:"Roboto",
 parseTime: false,
 fillOpacity:0.2
     }); 
}}); please check it

Comment: @RafiP Note you are using `JSON.stringify(response)` on `response`, and probably `response` is already a `JSON`, in that case you need `JSON.parse(response)`. To be sure, add `console.log(response, typeof response)` as the first line of the success callback and check the output of that.

Comment: Im using JSON.stringify(response) in console log its showing but in graph its not showing

Comment: @RafiP Probably you need const `data1 = JSON.parse(response);` in replace of `data1 = JSON.stringify(response);`. If you use the last one, `data1` will hold a `string` and you can't use that as the source of `Morris.Bar(...)`